# Fibonacci numbers using matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to write a code using matlab to compute the first 10 Fibonacci numbers.

The equation for calculating the Fibonacci numbers is

f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) 
knowing that 
f(0) = 1  and  f(1) = 1

The simple code that I wrote is

```
f(0) = 1;
f(1) = 1;

for i = 2 : 10
    f(i) = f(i-1) + f(i-2);
    str = [num2str(f(i))];
    disp(str)
end
```

This code is giving me error message in line 1:

> Attempted to access f(0); index must be a positive integer or logical.

On the other hand, when i modify the code to

```
f(1) = 1;
f(2) = 2;

for i = 3 : 10
    f(i) = f(i-1) + f(i-2);
    str = [num2str(f(i))];
    disp(str)
end
```

this is working fine.

But I need it to start and display the numbers from f(0).

Can you please tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: I guess that you have a programming background in some other language :). In MATLAB, for some reason, the first element get index 1.

Answer (score 5):

You can compute them non-recursively using [Binet's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html):

```
n = 1:10;
r = sqrt(5);
phi = (1+r)/2;
psi = (1-r)/2;
f = (phi.^n - psi.^n)./r;
```

Answer (score 2):

Matlab array indices are not zero based, so the first element is f(1) in your case.  What you can do is have f(1) and f(2) equal 1 and have the for loop go from 3:11.  If you actually want to display "f(0)" you can physically type it in a display string if needed.

If you need to display f(1) and f(2), you have some options.  First, would be to display them before you get into the loop.

```
str = str2num(f(1));
disp(str)
str = str2num(f(2));
disp(str)

for i = 3:11
...
```

Or, if it must be in the loop, you can add an if statement:

```
 for i = 3:11
   if i == 3
      str = str2num(f(1));
      disp(str)
      str = str2num(f(2));
      disp(str)
    end
  ...
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use recursive function of fibonacci.

**Create a function file named by `fibonacci`:**

```
function [ result ] = fibonacci( n )

if n==0||n==1
    result = n;

else
    result = fibonacci(n-2)+fibonacci(n-1);
end
end
```

**And write the code below to your command window:**

```
for n = 0:10
   fprintf('Fibonacci(%d)= %d\n', n, fibonacci(n));
end
```

**This is the output:**

```
>>
for n = 0:10
   fprintf('Fibonacci(%d)= %d\n', n, fibonacci(n));
end


Fibonacci(0)= 0
Fibonacci(1)= 1
Fibonacci(2)= 1
Fibonacci(3)= 2
Fibonacci(4)= 3
Fibonacci(5)= 5
Fibonacci(6)= 8
Fibonacci(7)= 13
Fibonacci(8)= 21
Fibonacci(9)= 34
Fibonacci(10)= 55
>>
```

Comment: Just note that recursion in Matlab is **very** slow, and this is a very inefficient way of calculating a list of Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: To clarify my comment, I don't exactly know why Matlab is bad at recursion, but it is. The reason your implementation is inefficient is because to calculate `Fibonacci(10)`, for example, you add `Fibonacci(9)` and `Fibonacii(8)`. Your code will go off and work out what those values are, but since you have already calculated them previously, you should just use the known values, you don't need to recalculate them. Because Matlab is based on arrays, it's more natural to use them, and loops where necessary, than recursion.

Comment: Thank you @Kamtal good to hear it from you.

Comment: @David, I see you and know it, just it isn' t the new implementation of mine, I have just adjusted it to OP case and shared it. Recursion is already inefficient method at all, I know it. The answer might be useful for somebody looks for implementation of fibonacci function in MATLAB not to calculate consecutive results of it..